# Why isn't my program using the variables?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make an object orientated JavaFX program but I have encountered a problem which I can't seem to fix, basically the Window variables all get set and when I print them to the console they are all set however when I come to use them in the start method it doesn't seem to acknowledge they are there.

Main class:

```
import com.mersey.ui.Window;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Window win = new Window();

        win.Create("Mersey", 980, 640, false);
        Window.launch(Window.class, args);
    }
}
```

Window class:

```
package com.mersey.ui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Window extends Application
{
    protected Stage   WindowStage;
    protected Pane    WindowRoot;
    protected Scene   WindowScene;
    protected String  WindowTitle;
    protected int     WindowWidth;
    protected int     WindowHeight;
    protected boolean WindowResizable;

    public void Create(String title, int width, int height, boolean resizable)
    {
        WindowTitle     = title;
        WindowWidth     = width;
        WindowHeight    = height;
        WindowResizable = resizable;

        /*
        System.out.print(WindowTitle+"\n");
        System.out.print(WindowWidth+"\n");
        System.out.print(WindowHeight+"\n");
        System.out.print(WindowResizable);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        WindowStage = stage;
        WindowRoot  = new Pane();
        WindowScene = new Scene(WindowRoot, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
        WindowStage.setScene(WindowScene);

        WindowStage.setTitle(WindowTitle);
        WindowStage.setWidth(WindowWidth);
        WindowStage.setHeight(WindowHeight);
        WindowStage.setMinWidth(WindowWidth);
        WindowStage.setMinHeight(WindowHeight);
        WindowStage.setResizable(WindowResizable);

        WindowStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note - name your variables starting with lowercase letters. Something like `windowRoot` or `windowWidth`.

Comment: I think its probably related to this line: Window.launch(Window.class, args);  I dont know this api youre using, but this doesnt appear to be passing the instance of Window you've created and called Create() on to the Window.launch method, meaning its probably launching a newly created instance, and not the instance you've constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think* what youre going to want to do here, is not construct the Window object then call Window.launch in the way you are now, but instead, funnel the values for the width height and all that via the String[] args passed into Window.launch. The documentation says that you can then retreive those values via getParameters(), so it would look something like this:

```
//in main
String[] launchArgs = new String[] {"Width=800", "Height=600"};
Window.launch(Window.class, launchArgs);

..........................


//in start(Stage)

String[] args = getParameters();
for (String s : args) {
     if (s.contains("Width")) {
        //parse and set the window width here
     }
}
```

See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String...)

Of course, this assumes you want to be able to supply arbitrary values for those class fields from within main. If not, I would just hard code a default value, or pull them from a config in the start(Stage) method.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help, i'll take a look into that now.